# Strophe.muc plugin and backbone inproper callback binding

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, strophe

After the first group message the strophe.muc plugin doesn't react on the following messages. 
I get the first presence, message and roster from the room, but all subsequent messages and presence stanzas will not trigger the functions. 
I think there is something wrong with the lines:

```
this.rooms[room].addHandler('message', msg_handler_cb);
this.rooms[room].addHandler('presence', pres_handler_cb);
this.rooms[room].addHandler('roster', roster_cb);
```

my code:

```
    join: function(){
          console.log("joining room");
          var self = this;
          connection.muc.join("room@conference.server", "john", self.onMessage,  self.onPresence, self.onRoster);
      },

    onMessage: function(message){            
          var self = this;       
         var body = $(message).text();
         var from = $(message).attr("from");
         console.log(body);
         console.log(from);
      },
      onPresence: function(presence){
          console.log("onPresence");
          console.log(presence);
      },
      onRoster: function(roster){
          console.log("onRoster");
          console.log(roster);
      },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handlers that wish to continue being invoked should return true.

So just append `return true;` to all your handlers.

It's mentioned in the docs:
http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.0.2/files2/strophe-js.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was not able to understand without your answer :-) Awesome!